# About Grails GORM's Where clause

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Just a simple question here

I uses the following **`WHERE query`**

```
def instance = ClassName.where{varone == 'A' &&
vartwo == 'B' && varthree == 'C'}.list()
```

And it returned me the object that i wanted --> ClassName(unsaved)

But when i tried to do the following

```
def instance2 = ClassName.where{varone == params.varone && 
vartwo == params.vartwo && varthree == params.varthree}.list()
```

It returned me the following which i couldn't do anything on it --->

```
grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria@somenumbershere
```

I don't understand what are the differences between these two.
 I need the 2nd query to return the same object as what the first query returned.

Comment: Your query should work. You are getting `grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria` then may be you have not called `.list` on it.

Comment: I tried with and without list() and it still returned me the same grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria. I wonder if the parameters used in the WHERE clause need to follow the type defined in the domain class? Like if varthree is a date type, then i need to convert params.varthree into date type right?